# What happened at the end of Code Geass R2?

Tags: code-geass

I believe I may have missed something.

At the end, Lelouch...

> died at the hands of his childhood friend, Suzaku, who was masquerading as Zero. But when did Lelouch order Suzaku, as Zero, to kill him (Lelouch)?

Comment: Zero and Lelouch were the same person. Are you sure you're not thinking of Susaku?

Answer (score 10):

This was all part or Lelouch's [Zero Requiem](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Requiem) plan.

> The plan involved focusing all of the world's hatred onto the tyrannical Emperor of the world (Lelouch) and killing him, as part of their plan for world peace.

Suzaku agreed to ally with Lelouch after the Tokyo Settlement incident with the F.L.E.I.J.A., specifically after his one-sided conversation with Jeremiah Gottwald.

> The only Geass order Lelouch gave Suzaku was the order to "live" on. (During the event on Shikinejima Island where he is ordered to kill Lelouch, who was Zero at the time)

Comment: This was shown when Nunally touched Lelouch after he was stabbed and saw the flashback of what they had planned.